# Passing variable as object

Tags: php

I have this function in Class A

```
function setParams($var1, Car $var2) {

}
```

And I call it from class B

```
$param1 = 'asd';
$param2 = 'lalala';
A::setParams($param1, $param2);
```

Now, param2 has to be instance of class Car and it won't allow me to pass that argument. What do I have to do in this case? This?

```
$param1 = 'asd';
$param2 = new Car();
$param->setValue('somevalue');

A::setParams($param1, $param2);
```

Or is there any other way?

Comment: You just answered your own question...

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I wanted to know if there's any other way. I know it's a dumb question...

Comment: Since you write the solution, what is your question? :)

Comment: @UberCrash The whole point of enforcing the argument's type is that only that type is allowed. What do you mean by "another way"? There is not supposed to be "another way".

Comment: `A::setParams($param1, new Car());`